# Read from a file and save integers to a list Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, text-files

I have a problem with multidimensional arrays in Python (MATLAB makes it look so easy...). I need to read numbers from a `.txt` file that has the following appearance:

```
 Region: Boston
 Item1   Item2
 0       100
 13      100
 27      62
 41      51
 -----------
 Region: Chicago
 Item1   Item2
 0       30
 15      50
 35      70
 45      1
```

I am new to Python, and I am struggling reading and saving the data into lists.
I've managed to do the following:

```
lines = [line.strip() for line in open(fileRadiance, 'r')]
for i in xrange(0, len(lines)):

words = lines[i].split();                        #Separates by whitespaces
if words[0] == "Region":
    Reg[Regcounter:] = words[2:]
    bsaveData = True;
if (bsaveData):
    Items[Itemcounte][0] = int(words[0]); Items[Itemcounte][1] = int(words[0]);
    ---or--- 
    Items[Itemcounter:] = words;
    Itemcounter+=1;
```

None of them produce what I am looking for, and I still did not fight against the second region. I'd love to have them as integers in a list like this:

```
 Items = [  [ [0,100],[13,100],[27,62],[41,51] ] ,  [ [0,30],[15,50],[35,70],[45,1] ] ]
```

So that if I want:

```
 Items[1][0][1] = 30;
 Items[1][0][1] + Items[0][2][0] = 57;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This.

```
lines = [line.strip() for line in open('fileRadiance.txt', 'r')]

Reg = []
Items = []
for line in lines:
    if "Item1" in line or '-----' in line:
        continue
    words = line.split()
    if words[0] == "Region:":
        Reg.append(words[1])
        Items.append([])
    else:
        Items[-1].append([int(i) for i in words])
```

And the output:

```
print Reg
>> ['Boston', 'Chicago']

print Items
>>[[[0, 100], [13, 100], [27, 62], [41, 51]], [[0, 30], [15, 50], [35, 70], [45, 1]]]
```

Comment: Wow, it works perfectly. I'll have a look at it closely! What's the meaning of the index [-1]?? Thanks so much.

Comment: Have a look at slices in any python tutorial. It takes the last item of your list (`list[-2]` would take the second last)

Comment: You should also look into pandas.  It would make this even easier, and would make accessing the data later easier too.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    Items = []
    Reg = []
    count = -1
    file_list = f.read().strip().split('\n')
    for line in file_list:
        if 'Item1' in line:
            Items.append([])
            count += 1
        if 'Region' in line:
            Reg.append(line.split(": ")[-1])

        # there is a space at the beginning of the line
        if line[1].isdigit():
            ints = [int(j) for j in line.split()]
            Items[count].append(ints)
    print(Items)
    print(Reg)
```